# Can't .map for a material RadioGroup

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have:

```
  const documentTypes = [
    'General',
    'Email',
    'Fiction story',
    'Blog post',
    'Newsletter',
    'Review',
    'Website content'
  ]
```

and

```
        <FormControl component="fieldset">
          <FormLabel component="legend">Document Type</FormLabel>
          <RadioGroup name="documentType" value={docType} onChange={handleChangeDoc}>
            {documentTypes.map((documentType, idx) => {
              <FormControlLabel value={documentType} control={<Radio />} label={documentType} key={idx} />
            })}
            <FormControlLabel value="other" control={<Radio />} label={<Input onFocus={() => setDocType('other')} />} />
          </RadioGroup>
        </FormControl>
```

but I don't see all of the options. Just the `other`. What am I doing wrong?

This is with `material-ui` for `react`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you only need to return the FormControlLabel in the map.

Options 1) remove the {} around the FormControlLabel

```
   <FormControl component="fieldset">
          <FormLabel component="legend">Document Type</FormLabel>
          <RadioGroup name="documentType" value={docType} onChange={handleChangeDoc}>
            {documentTypes.map((documentType, idx) => 
              <FormControlLabel value={documentType} control={<Radio />} label={documentType} key={idx} />
            )}
            <FormControlLabel value="other" control={<Radio />} label={<Input onFocus={() => setDocType('other')} />} />
          </RadioGroup>
        </FormControl>
```

Option 2) Just add return before FormControlLabel

```
<FormControl component="fieldset">
          <FormLabel component="legend">Document Type</FormLabel>
          <RadioGroup name="documentType" value={docType} onChange={handleChangeDoc}>
            {documentTypes.map((documentType, idx) => {
           return <FormControlLabel value={documentType} control={<Radio />} label={documentType} key={idx} />
            })}
            <FormControlLabel value="other" control={<Radio />} label={<Input onFocus={() => setDocType('other')} />} />
          </RadioGroup>
        </FormControl>
```

Comment: That did it - changing `{` to `(`

Comment: if it works for you please check as the answer. The parenthesis is more a style of code, using Eslint or Prettier you can config to use or not the parenthesis.